# Why isn't this url rewriting? Simple

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

Turn this:

```
http://example.com/products/
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/app.php?products
```

I also need support for queries at the end, for example::

this:

```
http://example.com/products/?foo=bar&boat=row
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/app.php?products&foo=bar&boat=row
```

This is my rewrite so far:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?\??([A-Za-z0-9\+=&]+)?$ app.php?$1&$2 [L]
```

This works for my first two example, however the second example only works for a url like

```
http://example.com/products/foo=bar&boat=row
```

I need to be able to have that question mark in there, which I think \?? in my rewrite should do, but it doesn't, and instad returns 404. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string can be appended using the `QSA` flag, you can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ app.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Andrew You're right, I needed a `$` to signify the end, I'll edit my answer